# Coursera like webapp with emphasis on student activities followup and encouragement

Tags: open-source, educational, framework

I am trying to build an app like [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/), with high emphasis on student activities follow up as a way of encouragement. So I am mainly concerned with the ability to have a newsfeed that shows messages like

- Student X finished Assignment X
- Student X submitted project Y in time
- Student X got a full grade for the 3rd time in a row

plus bonus and points system like that of [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/)

plus mobile app for simple notifications, newsfeed and points tracking

Are there open source frameworks or existing online systems that I can customize for my needs?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Open edX](http://code.edx.org/):

- free and open source
- MOOC plateform used by many universities

I guess that they might be interested in some gamification mode, but so far there is none.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Team Mates](http://teammatesv4.appspot.com/):

> TEAMMATES is an online peer evaluation and feedback system for
>   students. It is free for use, and all you require is to request for an
>   account from us. With TEAMMATES you can,
>
> Create new courses and easily upload student details. Create sessions.
>   There are two types of sessions:
>
> (a) Team peer evaluation sessions with fixed questions: These come
>   with preset questions optimized to measure contribution of team
>   members and give peer feedback to team members.
>
> (b) Feedback sessions with customizable questions: With these, you can
>   set your own questions and set visibility (who can see the responses)
>   and anonymity level per question. This is suitable for other feedback
>   paths such as peer feedback between teams and for feedback from
>   instructors to students.
>
> See here for more details about different session types.
>
> View reports of responses, and moderate them before publishing the
>   responses for students to view.

It also includes the option of peer review within teams or courses.

Not sure about it being fully open source it is **free**, already does a lot of what you are asking for and they are open to contributions and enhancements to the system and the source code is available [on-line](https://github.com/TEAMMATES/repo) you would have to look into the licence and hosting options.